# how to launch a second application in a second screen in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, screen, launcher, launching-application

I actually work on two little wpf application for track, one is on the principal computer, you can wrote the time of the pilot on, the second must display in a big screen connect to the principal computer in hdmi and just display the time to the pilot.

I have ever made everything and all work fine.

But when I launch the first application, I want the second application automaticaly launch in the second screen. I only find a solution with the Forms packages like :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens
```

But I work with WPF so I can't access to System.Windows.Forms.

Anyone as an idea of possible solution?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;` have you tried using this? 1 being the second monitor and 0 the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though it is a WPF app you can still reference System.Windows.Forms.
Simply right click on the project in solution explorer, add references, and select System.Windows.Forms.

Then use something like this: (you will also need a reference to System.Drawing)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MaximizeToSecondaryMonitor();
    }

    public void MaximizeToSecondaryMonitor()
    {
        var secondaryScreen = Screen.AllScreens.Where(s => !s.Primary).FirstOrDefault();

        if (secondaryScreen != null)
        {
            var workingArea = secondaryScreen.WorkingArea;
            this.Left = workingArea.Left;
            this.Top = workingArea.Top;
            this.Width = workingArea.Width;
            this.Height = workingArea.Height;

            if (this.IsLoaded)
            {
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[code taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753552/going-fullscreen-on-secondary-monitor)

Comment: Works better when launched from OnLoaded.